# Work Done by a Particular Force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work

A man pushes an 80 N crate a distance of 5.0 m upward along a frictionless slope that makes an angle of 30° with the horizontal. His force is parallel to the slope. If the speed of the crate decreases at a rate of 1.5 m/s², then what is the work done by the man?

---

NOTE: This is a practice problem our teacher gave us. We use 10 for g.

List item

First, I found the net force to be -12 N, so the force applied by the man is 28 N (only forces parallel to the incline are applied force and force of gravity, horizontal).

Then, since the force applied is 28 N and the displacement in the direction of the force is 10 m (5/sin30°), the work done by the man is 280 J.

But, the correct answer is 140 J. Where am I making my mistake? I think it's in my displacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue will be with the displacement, as you have noted.

The question does seem ambiguous when it uses the phrase "5.0m upward", and it has led you to imply this means there is a net vertical displacement of 5m. However, I think it is trying to convey that the displacement parallel to the slope is 5.0m (imagine it was phrased as "the man pushes a crate 5.0m *up/along* the slope")

If you use 5.0m as the displacement, you get the correct answer.